# C/C++ interface for Google Cloud KMS API

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I find it extraordinary that there isn't a PKCS#11 interface let alone the fact there is support for C#, Go, Java, Node.JS, PHP, Python and Ruby but no direct API support for C/C++. Did I miss something? Is it just a REST interface where you have to use one of Microsoft REST API library, Pistache or one of the other libraries out there?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Google Cloud publishes languages and client libraries in 7 languages:

- C# (.NET)
- Go
- Java
- Node.js
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby

And then you can always access the API directly via [REST](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest) or [gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rpc).

If you'd like to learn more about PKCS#11 in Cloud KMS, please reach out to the team using any of the methods on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/getting-support).

Comment: I've obviously read that page but where is the gRPC interface? It states that's eventually where it wants to go but I don't see any documentation for it? gRPC would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a C++ KMS library.

The code is here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/main/google/cloud/kms

The reference docs are here: https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/kms/latest

(No, this did not exist at the time you asked for it).